# Element id changes case

Tags: html, css

On the following page http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.thucydides%7Cthucydides-browsermob-plugin%7C0.9.220-RC2%7Cjar , if i inspect the GroupId input element ,it has the id 
id="groupid" ,but if i inspect the page's source code the input id becomes id="groupId".Why is there such behaviour ?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: I did not write any code ,and the whole description of problem is in the question.I just need to know the cause of such behaviour.

Comment: Line 3671 on http://search.maven.org/ajaxsolr/central-search-all.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking at same element, while you inspect it and when you look at source code. `groupid` is an `id` for the input field that is dynamically generated and 'groupId' is at another place.